# How can I alternate rotating a bone and its associated controls around its tail and its head?

Tags: bones

Is it possible to rig a hand such that I can drag the entire apparatus around in space with one control, rotate or pivot the entire hand apparatus around the wrist with a second control (as though waving), and with a third control rotate or pivot the entire hand apparatus around the fingertips (as though revving a motorcycle or pushing oneself off a surface by the fingertips)?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I use an IK constraint on your yellow colored bone and make a control bone for it that shares the location and size with the hand Bone (B in your drawing) but other than the hand bone it's not connected and not even parented to the IK Bone. On the Hand Bone I use a copy rotation constraint to copy the rotation of the control bone. If you do it that way you could set your cursor everywhere you want and transform the control bone around it.

**EDIT:**

you could also add another bone at the tip and parent the control bone to it to have controls at both positions

Comment: When using this method, is it possible to automate the selection of the correct pivot-to setting and the placement of the cursor based on some simple input (for example, which part of the control bone is clicked) such that the animator doesn't have to do it manually for every adjustment? For animations where the wrist is moving down while the fingertips are moving up and vice versa (say, a running quadruped), animating by repeatedly navigating the cursor position and pivot point menus to find the correct pose seems scarcely less laborious than counter-animating to achieve the same end result.

Comment: added solution to that